Images and css in Eclipse InfoCenter
I have a plugin for Eclipse InfoCenter with the following structure:
com.av.help.mega
--css
--html
-----description.html
--images
-----scheme1-7-1.svg
--META-INF
--build.properties
--plugin.xml
--toc.xml

When I try to specify the path to an image or to a css file in an html file, I get the following error in the browser:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

My html code:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/scheme1-7-1.svg">
</body>
</html>

Can you tell me how to correctly specify the path to images and css?

Since the HTML file is in the html folder the CSS is in the sibling folder css, it's ../css/styles.css.
